# Why do i get ValidationError on a model when i set paths to required: true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get this error for all the paths set to required: true in my mongoose schema even though the data is supplied during document creation:
ValidationError: targetaudience: Please enter your target audience, employeesize: Please enter your employee size, industry: Please enter your business industry, businessaddress: Please enter your business address, businesswebsite: Please enter your business website, businessname: Please enter your business name
Couldn't create campaigner: ValidationError: targetaudience: Please enter your target audience, employeesize: Please enter your employee size, industry: Please enter your business industry, businessaddress: Please enter your business address, businesswebsite: Please enter your business website, businessname: Please enter your business name

My code is below

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const campaignerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  businessname: { type: String, required: "Please enter your business name" },
  businesswebsite: {
    type: String,
    required: "Please enter your business website",
  },
  businessaddress: {
    type: String,
    required: "Please enter your business address",
  },
  industry: { type: String, required: "Please enter your business industry" },
  employeesize: { type: String, required: "Please enter your employee size" },
  targetaudience: {
    type: String,
    required: "Please enter your target audience",
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "NewReg",
  },
});

const Campaigner = mongoose.model("Campaigner", campaignerSchema);

export default Campaigner;
```

```
import Campaigner from "./campaignersModel.js";
import NewReg from "../users/userModel.js";
import asyncHandler from "./../../middleware/asyncHandler.js";

const createCampaigner = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    businessname,
    businesswebsite,
    businessaddress,
    industry,
    employeesize,
    targetaudience,
  } = req.body;
  const campaigner = new Campaigner({
    businessname: businessname, 
    businesswebsite: businesswebsite,
    businessaddress: businessaddress,
    industry: industry,
    employeesize: employeesize,
    targetaudience: targetaudience,
  });

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    campaigner.save(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Couldn't create campaigner: " + err);
      } else {
        NewReg.findOneAndUpdate(
          { email: req.session.passport.user },
          { user_role: "Campaigner" },
          { upsert: true, useFindAndModify: false },
          function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Update failed: " + err);
            } else {
              console.log(user);
            }
          }
        );
        res.status(200).json({ data: data });
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Please you have to log in");
    res.json({ message: "Please you have to log in" });
  }
});

export { createCampaigner };
```

Comment: try logging the value and type of each of those right before you create.